# How to get the world position of vertices on objects changed position

Tags: three.js

I searched around in SO to see if someone had a jsbin of the likes to show an example of this question so please forgive if this seems over asked.

Using r67 & r68
I have a simple THREE.Line named 'laser' that I move in some fashion, in this example I move and rotate it by mouse. Where ever the laser is I want to get the world cords of its vertices [0,1] so later I can attach a ray caster to those world cords.

I assume i'm just missing a core function that i'll dig through the source code and try to find. Hope this helps someone else in the future when I can update the jsbin.

Right now I just get its starting positions of 0,20 despite the matrix updates and such.
In the jsbin I left in some other commented out tries of code from other posts online.

Update: might have figured it out!

```
function render(){

// test finding the lasers vertices
laser.updateMatrixWorld(true);

// move laser
laser.rotation.z = MousePosition.x /50;
laser.position.x = MousePosition.x;
laser.position.y = MousePosition.y;

// which of these is needed?
laser.matrixWorldNeedsUpdate = true;
lasergeo.verticesNeedUpdate = true;

// --> this line looks to work
point1 = laser.localToWorld( lasergeo.vertices[1].clone() );
// console.log("point1", point1);
}
```

old
http://jsbin.com/yuqocemigacu/1/edit?html,js,console,output

new:
http://jsbin.com/yonaquzufeje/1/edit?html,js,output

In the new the refresh update skips the connection but thats another issue for another day.
Leaving this open cause I don't know if I have the correct method of doing this, could be do 900 matrix calculations and don't know it yet.